# player prefs got wrong value only in the google playstore

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play

i have player prefs in my game that save int value, the value of the player prefs suppose to be 0 at the start of the game , the value is actually 0 in the editor and on the build when i build the game on my phone, the problem occure when i apply my game to test on google play ,from some reason the player prefs gets the value 10(??) and i dont know why it's happend i checked the value with debug.log through logcat on my android and in regular build when i'm not apply the game to test on google play store i'ts shows the correct value 0 but on google play its shows the value 10, im also cleaned the playerprefs befour i made the build for google play and the regular build without googleplay so its not problem that i accidentally changed my playerprefs value or somthing like that, any idea what the issue?

Comment: Did you really delete the app before trying. Otherwise it will just update the app and not reset the playerprefs

Comment: @pixlhero Yes, I deleted the app And and reinstalled